# In laravel trying to register a company But when clicking on submit button it redirects me back on the form again and create no entry in DB

Tags: php, laravel

Here is my signup form

```
@extends('Layouts.master')

@section('title')
welcome
@endsection

@section('content')

@if(count($errors)>1)
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <ul>
                @foreach($errors->all() as $errors)
                    <li>{{$errors}}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
@endif
<div class="row" style="background-color:#FFF8F2;">

    <div class="col-lg-2">

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8">

        <div class="panel panel-danger">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3>Sign Up As A Company</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form action="{{route('companysignup')}}" method="post" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Enter Company Name</label>
                        <input placeholder="Enter Name"  name="company_name" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Enter Owner Name</label>
                        <input placeholder="Enter Owner Name" name="owner_name" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Enter Owner Email</label>
                        <input placeholder="Enter Owner Email" name="email" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Enter Phone Number</label>
                        <input placeholder="Enter Phone Number"  name="phone_number" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Company Type</label>
                        <select name="company_type" class="form-control">
                            <option>Combined</option>
                            <option>Individual</option>
                            <option>None</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Country</label>
                        <select name="country" class="form-control">
                            <option>Pakistan</option>
                            <option>Sudia Arabia</option>
                            <option>America</option>
                            <option>India</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    {{--<div class="form-group">--}}
                        {{--<label>Attach Registration Extract</label>--}}
                        {{--<input type="file" name="file">--}}
                    {{--</div>--}}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Enter short description about your company</label>
                        <textarea name="description" rows="3" class="form-control"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Enter  Password</label>
                        <input name="password " type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    {{csrf_field()}}
                    <input class="btn btn-outline btn-danger" type="submit" value="Submit">

                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2">

    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

here is my Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class Company extends Model
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'company';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    protected $fillable  = [
        'user_id',
        'company_name',
        'owner_name',
        'phone_number',
        'country',
        'company_type',
        'description'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */


    protected $hidden = [
        'remember_token'
    ];
}
```

Here is my web.php code

```
 Route::group(['middleware'=>['web']],function(){   
 Route::post('/companysignup',[
        'uses' => 'CompanyController@companySignUp',
        'as' => 'companysignup'
    ]);
});
```

Function is added company signup.

```
public function companySignUp(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request,[
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6',
        'company_name' => 'required|max:120',
        'owner_name' => 'required|max:120',
        'phone_number' => 'required|min:12|max:14',
        'company_type' => 'required',
        'country' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required'
    ]);

    $email = $request['email'];
    $password = bcrypt($request['password']);

    $user = new User();
    $user->email = $email;
    $user->password = $password;
    $user->role = 1; // Regular = 0, Company - 1
    $user->save();

    $company_name = $request['company_name'];
    $owner_name = $request['owner_name'];
    $country = $request['country'];
    $phone_number = $request['phone_number'];
    $company_type = $request['company_type'];
    $description = $request['description'];

    $company = new Company();
    $company->user_id = $user->id;
    $company->company_name = $company_name;
    $company->owner_name = $owner_name;
    $company->phone_number = $phone_number;
    $company->company_type = $company_type;
    $company->country = $country;
    $company->description = $description;

    $company->save();
    return view('frontend.user');
}
```

**Now you can check my function in controller Please suggest me solution for this problem .**

Comment: Show the `companySignUp` method please.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit you question and try to format your source code in source block formatting, including all `{` characters and other relevant lines. This will help other readers to understand your code.

Comment: Maybe it's because you have validation code in your signup function, show the contents of the function please.

Comment: here is the my validation  function  $this->validate($request,[
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6',
            'name' => 'required|max:120',
            'username' => 'required|max:120',
            'phone_number' => 'required|min:12|max:14',
            'gender' => 'required',
            'country' => 'required'
        ]);

Comment: I updated my question and added companysignup function.

Comment: Where you've got your `foreach` loop for the errors, you're setting creating a local `$errors` variable despite the `$errors` variable already existing as an object variable. Replace this with `foreach($errors->all() as $error` and then in then have `<li>{{ $error }}</li>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your validation is failing for some reasons. One of the reasons is that country is required but you don't send any country. Your country options are all empty. You did

```
<select name="country" class="form-control">
    <option>Pakistan</option>
    <option>Sudia Arabia</option>
    <option>America</option>
    <option>India</option>
</select>
```

In each of your options, add a value like

```
<option value="paskistan">Pakistan</option>
```

You are displaying errors in your view, so somehow it is supposed to display those validation errors to the screen.

Then the way you save your data, it's a little bit too much because your grab your variable and then use them. You could do both in one go

```
$company = Company::create([
    'user_id' => $user->id,
    'company_name' => $request->company_name,
    'owner_name' => $request->owner_name,
    //add all in your input the same way 
    'description' => $request->description
]);
```

And this will create a company and return the object to you.

Comment: Also worth noting that the `$request` variable is actually an object, not an associative array, you to access the attributes you need to use `$request->attr` or `$request->get('attr')`

Comment: If my answer helped you in the process, please mark it as the solution or at least upvote. That's how stackoverflow works. But if it didn't, all good.